# restoring the browsed attachment link unto the file input

Tags: javascript, jquery

So below is my snippet, so what's going on below is that when I click the button that has a text of "browse for attachment" the input file will then be triggered and then right after on select file (image), it will be then rendered to the image tag that has an id of "image_container" and then if click the button that has text of "Reset" the previous image url will be then restored unto the image container (#image_container). The variable save_src will hold the previous image source and the save_pic variable will hold the previous browse file link so when the user click the "Reset", the save_src will be put back unto the image container src and then the save_pic will be put back unto the input file.

The restoring of the image src is working (it restore the previous image) but the restoring of the previous browse file is unfortunately and sadly not working, it throws me this error

> "Uncaught InvalidStateError: Failed to set the 'value' property on
>   'HTMLInputElement': This input element accepts a filename, which may
>   only be programmatically set to the empty string."

Any ideas, help?

PS: this is an ajax upload image so I came with that some sort of convenient upload style.

```js
var save_src, save_pic;
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  $("#reset_button").click(function(){
       $("#employee_image_sidebar").prop("src", save_src);
       $("#browse_file").val(save_pic);
    });
  
  $("#browse_file").change(function(){
        if($(this).val() !== ""){
            save_src = $("#image_container").attr("src");
            save_pic = $("#browse_file").val();
          
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onloadend = function() {
              $("#image_container").prop("src", reader.result);
            }

            if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
              reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
            } else {
              $("#image_container").prop("src", "");
            }

            
        }
    });
  $("#browse_button").click(function(){
       $("#browse_file").trigger("click"); 
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,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" id="image_container"/>
<button id="browse_button">Browse for attachment</button>
<button id="reset_button">Reset</button>
<input type="file" id="browse_file" style="display: none;"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

The thing you want to do is not possible due to security restrictions. The error message is quite self-explanatory; there is no way to programmatically set the value of an `<input type="file">` element other than to clear it. Only the browser user is allowed to change it, using the browser's file chooser dialog. Remove the offending line, and all will be well:

```
$("#browse_file").val(save_pic); // XXX DELETE THIS
```